# No regresa valores mi droplist

Tags: c#, asp

En mi código mi `droplist` no me regresa los datos en mi `DropDownList`

```
 protected void LoadModel(string descripcion)
 {
     try
     {
         List<Model> items = ParseItem.ParseArrayToList(this.ws.SelectModelsByProductCode(descripcion));
         items.Insert(0, new Model() { Id_Model = 1, Description = "Seleccione..." });
         this.drpModel.DataSource = items;
         this.drpModel.DataTextField = "Description";
         this.drpModel.DataValueField = "Id_Modelo";
         this.drpModel.DataBind();

     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! saca el try, y fijate si no esta tirando un error.. porque asi como esta, si tira un error, no te estas enterando de nada...